# Checking request using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, request, fiddler

I'm writing some tests using Selenium in C#.

I'd like to check if some action on page sends request to specific host. I can check it manually using f.e. Fiddler, but I have no idea how to test it automatically.

Is there any way to connect Fiddler with Selenium and C#? Or maybe there's smarter solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim Evans posted a three part blog on getting http status codes via intergrating with fiddler, this may be of help.

http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/implementing-webdriver-http-status.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore), a library you can plug into your app with most of Fiddler's functionality